# Install IIS 6 Management Compatibility on IIS 8 / Windows 2012

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I cant access IIS server from console application because i need to install 6 Management Compatibility. I fixed this error on Windows 7, since its easy to find how to install 6 Management Compatibility.

[image]

Where and how i can do that on Windows 2012 / IIS 8 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Server 2012, go to Add Roles and Features.  If you have not installed the Web Server Role, be sure to select that from the Server Roles section.  When you get to the Role Services page for the Web Server Role, you will have the option to select IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

[image: Role Services screen]

Comment: Haha this new Windows GUI is good but sometimes is JOKE! :)

Comment: This was pretty much the same interface as Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 in terms of adding roles and features.  - Harold Wong

Comment: Im comparing with my desktop pc - Windows 7 :)